# angular-sweetalert + browserify: how to install/require/inject?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, sweetalert

I installed [angular-sweetalert](https://github.com/oitozero/ngSweetAlert) `^1.1.2` via `npm install --save angular-sweetalert` and tried to **inject** it:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    require('angular-sweetalert') // doesn't work
]);
```

I'm getting the following **Error**:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module undefined due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got undefined
```

It seems like it's [depending on more](https://github.com/oitozero/ngSweetAlert#install):

> 2. include the files in your app
>
>    i. SweetAlert.min.js
>
>    ii. sweet-alert.js OR sweet-alert.min.js
> 3. include the module in angular (i.e. in app.js) - oitozero.ngSweetAlert

Any ideas how to properly install/require the module?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module injector name is wrong, it should be 'oitozero.ngSweetAlert' rather than 'angular-sweetalert', also don't use require in the module injector. From [angular.module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module) says

> A module is a collection of services, directives, controllers,
>   filters, and configuration information. angular.module is used to
>   configure the $injector.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
   'oitozero.ngSweetAlert'
]);
```

PS: Make sure all the dependency files (step 2) are included before inject the library module.